# Can you add a limit to the number of times a method is invoked with InOrder?

Tags: java, mockito

This is using mockito 1.10.19.

I have a test which looks like this:

```
final InOrder inOrder = inOrder(foo);
inOrder.verify(foo).writeMetric("c", "m", 2, 2, 4, 4, 1, 4);
inOrder.verify(foo).writeMetric("c", "m2", 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 4);
inOrder.verify(foo).close();
inOrder.verifyNoMoreInteractions();
```

Now, I had to modify the behavior of `foo`; I updated the test with more data and for this data, the `writeMetric()` method should not be called any further.

Unfortunately, the test still succeeds where it should have failed. That is, I expect `writeMetric()` to be called twice and no more, but it is called 4 times (confirmed with debugging).

I found an ugly workaround: use `ArgumentCaptor`s for *all* method arguments then use:

```
inOrder.verify(foo, times(2)).writeMetric(captor1, etc etc);
```

and then check the contents of those captors' `.getAllValues()`. But it's rather ugly.

Ideally, I'd have liked to modify the test above like so:

```
final InOrder inOrder = inOrder(foo);
inOrder.verify(foo).writeMetric("c", "m", 2, 2, 4, 4, 1, 4);
inOrder.verify(foo).writeMetric("c", "m2", 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 4);
// Does not exist but it'd be nice if it did...
inOrder.verify(foo, noMore()).writeMetric(anyString(), etc etc);
inOrder.verify(foo).close();
inOrder.verifyNoMoreInteractions();
```

Is it possible other than my ugly workaround? Given the number of arguments to the method, this is rather a handful to write/manage...

Comment: I wonder why you call `verify` and `verifyNoMoreInteractions` on `inOrder`. These are static methods in the `Mockito` class, so shouldn't you call `Mocktio.verify(foo).....` and `Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(foo)`? Can you try that? A small test showed me, that it work that way.

Comment: @Tom the static verify() methods don't care about orders of invocations; I do...

Comment: Ah ok, thought `InOrder` was one of your classes. But my [small example](http://pastebin.com/xMaSKvSQ) still works correctly. Is `writeMetric` really called on `foo`? Or can you try to create a small example?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [you're not the first one](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=501) to ask for this feature.

You should be able to do almost exactly what you suggested, and it seems to work, as long as the extra invocations come after the expected one.

```
final InOrder inOrder = inOrder(foo);
inOrder.verify(foo).writeMetric("c", "m", 2, 2, 4, 4, 1, 4);
inOrder.verify(foo).writeMetric("c", "m2", 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 4);
inOrder.verify(foo, never()).writeMetric(anyString(), anyString(), anyInt(), anyInt(), anyInt(), anyInt(), anyInt(), anyInt());
inOrder.verify(foo).close();
```

The implicit `times(1)` verifications allow those first calls to happen, and then the `never()` verification prevents further calls. However, as above feature request notes, there is no good way to avoid other `writeMetric` calls in between or before your expected calls, unless you use `Mockito.verifyNoInteractions(foo)`. But that will also check other method calls  as well (which might be what you want). `inOrder.verifyNoMoreInteractions()` does not seem to be too useful in this case. Unclear if it is ever really useful.